How does Withholding work for a foreign company?
I'm an American citizen who's applied for a remote job for a company based in Dubai. The job agent asked for my desired payrate, but I didn't know how to answer.
Normally I would mention a certain value for a W2 job (the company withholds taxes on behalf of the government) and another for a 1099 job (I'd be responsible for those taxes plus self-employment tax).
But I don't know how it works when the company is based overseas. They may have a US-based affiliate or something, in which case I can use my normal rates. If they hire me as a independant contractor, I'd ask for my 1099 rate (whether or not they actually give me a 1099 form).
But if they want to hire me as a standard employee, would they use a W2 and withhold American taxes? Or Dubai taxes? Would they pay me without withholding?
(The agent does not know the answer.)

Good question. Also, this question would be a perfect fit for "Personal Finance and Money - Stack Exchange" as I have seen lots of similar questions on that site. Here is the link: https://money.stackexchange.com/

You will be employed. You will not be collecting unemployment. Employed American citizens pay taxes, regardless if it’s a remote job, you will be required to pay taxes on the income you earn. The bank will report that income. The fact they don’t know how to hire you properly suggests this job offer might be a scam.

@Donald  The job agent who didn't have the information is a third-party guy in England, so its more forgivable that he wouldn't know. I suspect the company itself is very well-versed in international employment, but I think its too early to reach out to their HR department (I haven't even had the interview yet)

If the company isn't withholding, you will have to make estimated tax payments.


(The agent does not know the answer.)

The agent is paid to know the answer!  It's really important and you also need to understand things like expenses etc. Go back and insist he does his job.

Say “Find out.”

This presumes that the agent is US based or in some jurisdiction that does withholding like the US, which may not be the case.  The agent may even be outside Dubai.  It'd be nice if the agent could provide this info, but it's not necessarily a "duty".

If they're hiring you as an employee while you live in the US they'd need a US based subsidiary to do so, and would then have to pay normal withholding, etc.
Alternate options would be employing you indirectly through a US contracting firm, in which case that company would pay you as a W-2 doing withholding and probably offering some (likely limited) benefits.
The last legal way would be to hire you directly as a 1099 in which case you'd be responsible for all taxes, etc directly.
If they offered to pay you in some other fashion without a W-2 or 1099, it's a huge red flag that you're almost certainly communicating with a scammer of some sort, not a legitimate company.

"If they're hiring you as an employee while you live in the US they'd need a US based subsidiary to do so" What makes you say this?

Hiring US residents through a US-based office (not necessarily subsidy) would make the company's bookkeeping easier, which is why it's often done that way... but is not essential.
